# Opening a port on OpenSUSE

Tags: opensuse, port

I am trying to open a port for OpenSUSE for VPN on Windows Server. I have opened the port from Yast 1701

But not success.
After this I've opened the port from iptables. Still nothing. The 1702 port i've opened was for testing. But no success either.
Any idea what is wrong ?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search enginre results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: Also, the screenshot shows Yast with ill-configured line drawing characters and bad contrast between font colour and background.I won't try to read this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `iptables` or any other firewall cannot **open** a port by itself - only an application that *uses* that port can do that.

What a firewall can do is **unblock** a port to allow connections to it. But without an application that either *listens* for incoming connections or opens an outgoing connection using that port, an unblocked port will still be closed.

A blocked port will typically *drop* incoming packets, ignoring them completely. For the person attempting to connect to a blocked port, this typically shows as a "connection timed out" error after waiting a while.

An unblocked but closed port will typically actively *reject* incoming connections: the person attempting to connect will get a "connection refused" error message pretty much immediately. Depending on network protocol used, this rejection can usually happen in one of two ways: for TCP, a TCP Reset packet is usually sent. The other option is to send an ICMP error message packet, which is the norm with UDP and may also be used with TCP.

Port 1701 is typically used by a L2TP VPN protocol, which is often used together with IPsec.

On OpenSuSE, IPsec is provided by package `strongswan` and L2TP by `xl2tpd`. You may also want the `yast2-vpn` package to allow for easy configuration (either client or server side) through YaST. You would need to install and configure these to suit your requirements, as they won't be enabled by default.

It is unclear whether you plan to use your OpenSuSE as a VPN server (to accept incoming VPN connections from the Windows server) or as a VPN client (to make an outgoing VPN connection to the Windows server); in either case, these links to OpenSuSE's own documentation may be useful:

https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:VPN

https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:VPN/YaST_VPN_Module